# Checking multiple MySQL columns against a single value

Tags: mysql

I have a very simple question: how can I check multiple MySQL columns against a single value? I'm looking basically for the opposite of the `IN (1, 2, 3, 4)` where one can check a single column against multiple values.

I know I can just write multiple sentences, but I was looking for a more elegant solution. I'm using PHP. Thank you!

Comment: Why didn't you try the opposite. The opposite works. First try then ask the  question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use IN only like below:

```
select * from TableName where 2 IN (ColumnOne,ColumnTwo,ColumnThree)
```

Answer (score 6):

is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT *
FROM   tableName
WHERE  1 IN (col1, col2, col3, col4)
```

Comment: Thanks, I also found out that this works:

`SELECT *
FROM tableNAME
WHERE (col1, col2) = value`

Comment: Actually there is a problem with the solution you provided. The IN statement works as an OR operand. What I need is that the conditions are met for ALL the columns (AND operand).

Comment: then why not execute `SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE col1 = 1 AND col2 = 1 AND col3 = 1 AND col4 = 1` ?

Comment: I know, I was just asking if there was a more elegant solution for the problem, avoiding to get the query long (I'm creating it in a PHP script and the criteria is a quite long class property). If there is no IN-like operand that uses an AND logic instead of an OR logic I guess I have no other way.

Comment: I need same...but just need like on value...

`WHERE  'value%' IN (col1, col2, col3, col4)`

I want to run a big query with large data..

Answer (score 0):

How about using `or` logical operator on your `where` clause?

```
select *
  from your_table
 where col_a = 'value'
    or col_b = 'value'
    or col_c = 'value'
    or col_d = 'value'
```